# Previously working code suddenly won't build

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, camera-calibration

So I've been working on this camera calibration code in C++ using OpenCV 3.0.0 in Visual Studio 2013.  I ran into an error that I wasn't sure was caused by an issue related to my code or was a compiler issue, so I commented out the bulk of my code, created a test code file, built/ran it, then commented out all of that code, uncommented the original code and built/ran it.

All of a sudden the code that had been working (ish) previously won't even build.  I am getting errors such as "lambda capture variable not found", Intellisense says all my variables are undefined, and more.  I have no idea why this happened when previously my code was building and running.  I have cleaned the project and solution and deleted the test code file, but nothing has helped.  Any ideas for what would cause this?

Code is shown below, and errors I am getting are below that.

```
    //Camera Calibration
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    #include <opencv2/core.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>


    #ifndef _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    # define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #endif

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    static void help()
    {
        cout << "This is a camera calibration sample." << endl
            << "Usage: calibration configurationFile" << endl
            << "Near the sample file you'll find the configuration file, which has detailed help of "
            "how to edit it.  It may be any OpenCV supported file format     XML/YAML." << endl;
    }
    class Settings
    {
    public:
        Settings() : goodInput(false) {}
        enum Pattern { NOT_EXISTING, CHESSBOARD, CIRCLES_GRID, ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID };
        enum InputType { INVALID, CAMERA, VIDEO_FILE, IMAGE_LIST };

        void write(FileStorage& fs) const                        //Write serialization for this class
        {
            fs << "{"
            << "BoardSize_Width" << boardSize.width
            << "BoardSize_Height" << boardSize.height
            << "Square_Size" << squareSize
            << "Calibrate_Pattern" << patternToUse
            << "Calibrate_NrOfFrameToUse" << nrFrames
            << "Calibrate_FixAspectRatio" << aspectRatio
            << "Calibrate_AssumeZeroTangentialDistortion" << calibZeroTangentDist
            << "Calibrate_FixPrincipalPointAtTheCenter" << calibFixPrincipalPoint

            << "Write_DetectedFeaturePoints" << writePoints
            << "Write_extrinsicParameters" << writeExtrinsics
            << "Write_outputFileName" << outputFileName

            << "Show_UndistortedImage" << showUndistorsed

            << "Input_FlipAroundHorizontalAxis" << flipVertical
            << "Input_Delay" << delay
            << "Input" << input
            << "}";
    }
    void read(const FileNode& node)                          //Read serialization for this class
    {
        node["BoardSize_Width"] >> boardSize.width;
        node["BoardSize_Height"] >> boardSize.height;
        node["Calibrate_Pattern"] >> patternToUse;
        node["Square_Size"] >> squareSize;
        node["Calibrate_NrOfFrameToUse"] >> nrFrames;
        node["Calibrate_FixAspectRatio"] >> aspectRatio;
        node["Write_DetectedFeaturePoints"] >> writePoints;
        node["Write_extrinsicParameters"] >> writeExtrinsics;
        node["Write_outputFileName"] >> outputFileName;
        node["Calibrate_AssumeZeroTangentialDistortion"] >> calibZeroTangentDist;
        node["Calibrate_FixPrincipalPointAtTheCenter"] >> calibFixPrincipalPoint;
        node["Input_FlipAroundHorizontalAxis"] >> flipVertical;
        node["Show_UndistortedImage"] >> showUndistorsed;
        node["Input"] >> input;
        node["Input_Delay"] >> delay;
        validate();
    }
    void validate()
    {
        goodInput = true;
        if (boardSize.width <= 0 || boardSize.height <= 0)
        {
            cerr << "Invalid Board size: " << boardSize.width << " " << boardSize.height << endl;
            goodInput = false;
        }
        if (squareSize <= 10e-6)
        {
            cerr << "Invalid square size " << squareSize << endl;
            goodInput = false;
        }
        if (nrFrames <= 0)
        {
            cerr << "Invalid number of frames " << nrFrames << endl;
            goodInput = false;
        }

        if (input.empty())      // Check for valid input
            inputType = INVALID;
        else
        {
            if (input[0] >= '0' && input[0] <= '9')
            {
                stringstream ss(input);
                ss >> cameraID;
                inputType = CAMERA;
            }
            else
            {
                if (readStringList(input, imageList))
                {
                    inputType = IMAGE_LIST;
                    nrFrames = (nrFrames < (int)imageList.size()) ? nrFrames : (int)imageList.size();
                }
                else
                    inputType = VIDEO_FILE;
            }
            if (inputType == CAMERA)
                inputCapture.open(cameraID);
            if (inputType == VIDEO_FILE)
                inputCapture.open(input);
            if (inputType != IMAGE_LIST && !inputCapture.isOpened())
                inputType = INVALID;
        }
        if (inputType == INVALID)
        {
            cerr << " Input does not exist: " << input;
            goodInput = false;
        }

        flag = 0;
        if (calibFixPrincipalPoint) flag |= CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT;
        if (calibZeroTangentDist)   flag |= CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST;
        if (aspectRatio)            flag |= CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO;


        calibrationPattern = NOT_EXISTING;
        if (!patternToUse.compare("CHESSBOARD")) calibrationPattern = CHESSBOARD;
        if (!patternToUse.compare("CIRCLES_GRID")) calibrationPattern = CIRCLES_GRID;
        if (!patternToUse.compare("ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID")) calibrationPattern = ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID;
        if (calibrationPattern == NOT_EXISTING)
        {
            cerr << " Camera calibration mode does not exist: " << patternToUse << endl;
            goodInput = false;
        }
        atImageList = 0;

    }
    Mat nextImage()
    {
        Mat result;
        if (inputCapture.isOpened())
        {
            Mat view0;
            inputCapture >> view0;
            view0.copyTo(result);
        }
        else if (atImageList < imageList.size())
            result = imread(imageList[atImageList++], IMREAD_COLOR);

        return result;
    }

    static bool readStringList(const string& filename, vector<string>& l)
    {
        l.clear();
        FileStorage fs(filename, FileStorage::READ);
        if (!fs.isOpened())
            return false;
        FileNode n = fs.getFirstTopLevelNode();
        if (n.type() != FileNode::SEQ)
            return false;
        FileNodeIterator it = n.begin(), it_end = n.end();
        for (; it != it_end; ++it)
            l.push_back((string)*it);
        return true;
    }
public:
    Size boardSize;              // The size of the board -> Number of items by width and height
    Pattern calibrationPattern;  // One of the Chessboard, circles, or asymmetric circle pattern
    float squareSize;            // The size of a square in your defined unit (point, millimeter,etc).
    int nrFrames;                // The number of frames to use from the input for calibration
    float aspectRatio;           // The aspect ratio
    int delay;                   // In case of a video input
    bool writePoints;            // Write detected feature points
    bool writeExtrinsics;        // Write extrinsic parameters
    bool calibZeroTangentDist;   // Assume zero tangential distortion
    bool calibFixPrincipalPoint; // Fix the principal point at the center
    bool flipVertical;           // Flip the captured images around the horizontal axis
    string outputFileName;       // The name of the file where to write
    bool showUndistorsed;        // Show undistorted images after calibration
    string input;                // The input ->

    int cameraID;
    vector<string> imageList;
    size_t atImageList;
    VideoCapture inputCapture;
    InputType inputType;
    bool goodInput;
    int flag;

private:
    string patternToUse;


};

static inline void read(const FileNode& node, Settings& x, const Settings& default_value = Settings())
{
    if (node.empty())
        x = default_value;
    else
        x.read(node);
}

static inline void write(FileStorage& fs, const String&, const Settings& s)
{
    s.write(fs);
}

enum { DETECTION = 0, CAPTURING = 1, CALIBRATED = 2 };

bool runCalibrationAndSave(Settings& s, Size imageSize, Mat&  cameraMatrix, Mat& distCoeffs,
    vector<vector<Point2f> > imagePoints);

bool actually_findChessboardCorners(Mat& frame, Size& size, Mat& corners, int flags);

double actually_calibrateCamera(vector<vector<Point3f>> _objectPoints,
    vector<vector<Point2f>> _imagePoints,
    Size imageSize, InputOutputArray _cameraMatrix, InputOutputArray _distCoeffs,
    OutputArrayOfArrays _rvecs, OutputArrayOfArrays _tvecs, int flags, TermCriteria criteria);

static Mat prepareDistCoeffs(Mat& distCoeffs0, int rtype);
static Mat prepareCameraMatrix(Mat& cameraMatrix0, int rtype);
static void actually_collectCalibrationData(vector<vector<Point3f>> objectPoints,
    vector<vector<Point2f>> imagePoints1,
    InputArrayOfArrays imagePoints2,
    Mat& objPtMat, Mat& imgPtMat1, Mat* imgPtMat2,
    Mat& npoints);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    help();

    ![file_read]
        Settings s;
    const string inputSettingsFile = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "default.xml";
    FileStorage fs(inputSettingsFile, FileStorage::READ); // Read the settings
    if (!fs.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Could not open the configuration file: \"" << inputSettingsFile << "\"" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    fs["Settings"] >> s;
    fs.release();                                         // close Settings file
    ![file_read]

        FileStorage fout("settings.yml", FileStorage::WRITE); // write config as YAML
    fout << "Settings" << s;

    if (!s.goodInput)
    {
        cout << "Invalid input detected. Application stopping. " << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    vector<vector<Point2f>> imagePoints;
    Mat cameraMatrix, distCoeffs;
    Size imageSize;
    int mode = s.inputType == Settings::IMAGE_LIST ? CAPTURING : DETECTION;
    clock_t prevTimestamp = 0;
    const Scalar RED(0, 0, 255), GREEN(0, 255, 0);
    const char ESC_KEY = 27;

    ![get_input]
        for (int i = 0;; ++i)
        {
            Mat view_large;
            Mat view;
            bool blinkOutput = false;

            view_large = s.nextImage();
            if (!view_large.empty())
                resize(view_large, view, Size(), .5, .5);

            ---- - If no more image, or got enough, then stop calibration and show result------------ -
                if (mode == CAPTURING && imagePoints.size() >= (size_t)s.nrFrames)
                {
                    if (runCalibrationAndSave(s, imageSize, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, imagePoints))
                        mode = CALIBRATED;
                    else
                        mode = DETECTION;
                }
            if (view.empty())          // If there are no more images stop the loop
            {
                if calibration threshold was not reached yet, calibrate now
                    if (mode != CALIBRATED && !imagePoints.empty())
                        runCalibrationAndSave(s, imageSize, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, imagePoints);
                break;
            }
            ![get_input]

                imageSize = view.size();  // Format input image.
            if (s.flipVertical)    flip(view, view, 0);

            ![find_pattern]
                Mat pointBuf;
            vector<Point2f> corners;
            bool found;
            switch (s.calibrationPattern) // Find feature points on the input format
            {
            case Settings::CHESSBOARD:
                found = actually_findChessboardCorners(view, s.boardSize, pointBuf,
                    CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK | CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);

                break;
            case Settings::CIRCLES_GRID:
                found = findCirclesGrid(view, s.boardSize, pointBuf);
                break;
            case Settings::ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID:
                found = findCirclesGrid(view, s.boardSize, pointBuf, CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID);
                break;
            default:
                found = false;
                break;
            }
            ![find_pattern]
                ![pattern_found]
                if (found)                // If done with success,
                {
                    improve the found corners' coordinate accuracy for chessboard
                        if (s.calibrationPattern == Settings::CHESSBOARD)
                        {
                            Mat viewGray;
                            cvtColor(view, viewGray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
                            cornerSubPix(viewGray, pointBuf, Size(11, 11),
                                Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(TermCriteria::EPS + TermCriteria::COUNT, 30, 0.1));
                            corners.assign((Point2f*)pointBuf.datastart, (Point2f*)pointBuf.dataend);
                            corners.resize(54);

                        }

                    if (mode == CAPTURING &&  // For camera only take new samples after delay time
                        (!s.inputCapture.isOpened() || clock() - prevTimestamp > s.delay*1e-3*CLOCKS_PER_SEC))
                    {
                        imagePoints.push_back(corners);
                        prevTimestamp = (long)clock();
                        blinkOutput = s.inputCapture.isOpened();
                    }

                    Draw the corners.
                        drawChessboardCorners(view, s.boardSize, pointBuf, found);
                }
            ![pattern_found]
                ---------------------------- - Output Text------------------------------------------------
                ![output_text]
                string msg = (mode == CAPTURING) ? "100/100" :
                mode == CALIBRATED ? "Calibrated" : "Press 'g' to start";
            int baseLine = 0;
            Size textSize = getTextSize(msg, 1, 1, 1, &baseLine);
            Point textOrigin(view.cols - 2 * textSize.width - 10, view.rows - 2 * baseLine - 10);

            if (mode == CAPTURING)
            {
                if (s.showUndistorsed)
                    msg = format("%d/%d Undist", (int)imagePoints.size(), s.nrFrames);
                else
                    msg = format("%d/%d", (int)imagePoints.size(), s.nrFrames);
            }

            putText(view, msg, textOrigin, 1, 1, mode == CALIBRATED ? GREEN : RED);

            if (blinkOutput)
                bitwise_not(view, view);
            ![output_text]
                ------------------------ - Video capture  output  undistorted------------------------------
                ![output_undistorted]
                if (mode == CALIBRATED && s.showUndistorsed)
                {
                    Mat temp = view.clone();
                    undistort(temp, view, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs);
                }
            ![output_undistorted]
                ------------------------------Show image and check for input commands------------------ -
                ![await_input]
                imshow("Image View", view);
            char key = (char)waitKey(s.inputCapture.isOpened() ? 50 : s.delay);

            if (key == ESC_KEY)
                break;

            if (key == 'u' && mode == CALIBRATED)
                s.showUndistorsed = !s.showUndistorsed;

            if (s.inputCapture.isOpened() && key == 'g')
            {
                mode = CAPTURING;
                imagePoints.clear();
            }
            ![await_input]
        }

    ---------------------- - Show the undistorted image for the image list------------------------
        ![show_results]
        if (s.inputType == Settings::IMAGE_LIST && s.showUndistorsed)
        {
            Mat view, rview, map1, map2;
            initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, Mat(),
                getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, imageSize, 1, imageSize, 0),
                imageSize, CV_16SC2, map1, map2);

            for (size_t i = 0; i < s.imageList.size(); i++)
            {
                view = imread(s.imageList[i], 1);
                if (view.empty())
                    continue;
                remap(view, rview, map1, map2, INTER_LINEAR);
                imshow("Image View", rview);
                char c = (char)waitKey();
                if (c == ESC_KEY || c == 'q' || c == 'Q')
                    break;
            }
        }
    ![show_results]

        return 0;
}

![compute_errors]
static double computeReprojectionErrors(const vector<vector<Point3f> >& objectPoints,
const vector<vector<Point2f>>& imagePoints,
const vector<Mat>& rvecs, const vector<Mat>& tvecs,
const Mat& cameraMatrix, const Mat& distCoeffs,
vector<float>& perViewErrors)
{
    vector<Point2f> imagePoints2;
    size_t totalPoints = 0;
    double totalErr = 0, err;
    perViewErrors.resize(objectPoints.size());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < objectPoints.size(); ++i)
    {
        projectPoints(objectPoints[i], rvecs[i], tvecs[i], cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, imagePoints2);
        err = norm(imagePoints[i], imagePoints2, NORM_L2);

        size_t n = objectPoints[i].size();
        perViewErrors[i] = (float)std::sqrt(err*err / n);
        totalErr += err*err;
        totalPoints += n;
    }

    return std::sqrt(totalErr / totalPoints);
}
![compute_errors]
![board_corners]
static void calcBoardCornerPositions(Size boardSize, float squareSize, vector<Point3f>& corners,
Settings::Pattern patternType /*= Settings::CHESSBOARD*/)
{
    corners.clear();
    corners.reserve(54);
    switch (patternType)
    {
    case Settings::CHESSBOARD:
    case Settings::CIRCLES_GRID:
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize.height; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < boardSize.width; ++j)
                corners.push_back(Point3f(j*squareSize, i*squareSize, 0.0f));
        break;

    case Settings::ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID:
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize.height; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < boardSize.width; j++)
                corners.push_back(Point3f((2 * j + i % 2)*squareSize, i*squareSize, 0));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
![board_corners]
static bool runCalibration(Settings& s, Size& imageSize, Mat& cameraMatrix, Mat& distCoeffs,
vector<vector<Point2f>> imagePoints, vector<Mat>& rvecs, vector<Mat>& tvecs,
vector<float>& reprojErrs, double& totalAvgErr)
{
    ![fixed_aspect]
        cameraMatrix = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
    if (s.flag & CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO)
        cameraMatrix.at<double>(0, 0) = s.aspectRatio;
    ![fixed_aspect]

        distCoeffs = Mat::zeros(8, 1, CV_64F);


    vector<vector<Point3f> > objectPoints(1);
    calcBoardCornerPositions(s.boardSize, s.squareSize, objectPoints[0], s.calibrationPattern);


    objectPoints.resize(imagePoints.size(), objectPoints[0]);
    objectPoints.resize(imagePoints.size());

    TermCriteria term;
    double rms = actually_calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints, imageSize, cameraMatrix,
        distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs, s.flag | CALIB_FIX_K4 | CALIB_FIX_K5, term);

    cout << "Re-projection error reported by calibrateCamera: " << rms << endl;

    bool ok = checkRange(cameraMatrix) && checkRange(distCoeffs);

    totalAvgErr = computeReprojectionErrors(objectPoints, imagePoints,
        rvecs, tvecs, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, reprojErrs);

    return ok;
}

Print camera parameters to the output file
static void saveCameraParams(Settings& s, Size& imageSize, Mat& cameraMatrix, Mat& distCoeffs,
const vector<Mat>& rvecs, const vector<Mat>& tvecs,
const vector<float>& reprojErrs, const vector<vector<Point2f>>& imagePoints,
double totalAvgErr)
{
    FileStorage fs(s.outputFileName, FileStorage::WRITE);

    time_t tm;
    time(&tm);
    struct tm *t2 = localtime(&tm);
    char buf[1024];
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%c", t2);

    fs << "calibration_time" << buf;

    if (!rvecs.empty() || !reprojErrs.empty())
        fs << "nr_of_frames" << (int)std::max(rvecs.size(), reprojErrs.size());
    fs << "image_width" << imageSize.width;
    fs << "image_height" << imageSize.height;
    fs << "board_width" << s.boardSize.width;
    fs << "board_height" << s.boardSize.height;
    fs << "square_size" << s.squareSize;

    if (s.flag & CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO)
        fs << "fix_aspect_ratio" << s.aspectRatio;

    if (s.flag)
    {
        sprintf(buf, "flags: %s%s%s%s",
            s.flag & CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS ? " +use_intrinsic_guess" : "",
            s.flag & CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO ? " +fix_aspect_ratio" : "",
            s.flag & CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT ? " +fix_principal_point" : "",
            s.flag & CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST ? " +zero_tangent_dist" : "");
        cvWriteComment(*fs, buf, 0);
    }

    fs << "flags" << s.flag;

    fs << "camera_matrix" << cameraMatrix;
    fs << "distortion_coefficients" << distCoeffs;

    fs << "avg_reprojection_error" << totalAvgErr;
    if (s.writeExtrinsics && !reprojErrs.empty())
        fs << "per_view_reprojection_errors" << Mat(reprojErrs);

    if (s.writeExtrinsics && !rvecs.empty() && !tvecs.empty())
    {
        CV_Assert(rvecs[0].type() == tvecs[0].type());
        Mat bigmat((int)rvecs.size(), 6, rvecs[0].type());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rvecs.size(); i++)
        {
            Mat r = bigmat(Range(int(i), int(i + 1)), Range(0, 3));
            Mat t = bigmat(Range(int(i), int(i + 1)), Range(3, 6));

            CV_Assert(rvecs[i].rows == 3 && rvecs[i].cols == 1);
            CV_Assert(tvecs[i].rows == 3 && tvecs[i].cols == 1);
            *.t() is MatExpr(not Mat) so we can use assignment operator
                r = rvecs[i].t();
            t = tvecs[i].t();
        }
        cvWriteComment(*fs, "a set of 6-tuples (rotation vector + translation vector) for each view", 0);
        fs << "extrinsic_parameters" << bigmat;
    }

    if (s.writePoints && !imagePoints.empty())
    {
        Mat imagePtMat((int)imagePoints.size(), (int)imagePoints[0].size(), CV_32FC2);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < imagePoints.size(); i++)
        {
            Mat r = imagePtMat.row(int(i)).reshape(2, imagePtMat.cols);
            Mat imgpti(imagePoints[i]);
            imgpti.copyTo(r);
        }
        fs << "image_points" << imagePtMat;
    }
}

![run_and_save]
bool runCalibrationAndSave(Settings& s, Size imageSize, Mat& cameraMatrix, Mat& distCoeffs,
vector<vector<Point2f>> imagePoints)
{
    vector<Mat> rvecs, tvecs;
    vector<float> reprojErrs;
    double totalAvgErr = 0;

    bool ok = runCalibration(s, imageSize, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, imagePoints, rvecs, tvecs, reprojErrs,
        totalAvgErr);
    cout << (ok ? "Calibration succeeded" : "Calibration failed")
        << ". avg re projection error = " << totalAvgErr << endl;

    if (ok)
        saveCameraParams(s, imageSize, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs, reprojErrs, imagePoints,
        totalAvgErr);
    return ok;
}
bool actually_findChessboardCorners(Mat& frame, Size& size, Mat& corners, int flags) {
    int count = size.area() * 2;
    corners.create(count, 1, CV_32FC2);
    CvMat _image = frame;
    bool ok = cvFindChessboardCorners(&_image, size,
        reinterpret_cast<CvPoint2D32f*>(corners.data),
        &count, flags) > 0;
    return ok;
}

![run_and_save]
double actually_calibrateCamera(vector<vector<Point3f>> _objectPoints,
vector<vector<Point2f>> _imagePoints,
Size imageSize, InputOutputArray _cameraMatrix, InputOutputArray _distCoeffs,
OutputArrayOfArrays& _rvecs, OutputArrayOfArrays& _tvecs, int flags, TermCriteria criteria)
{
    int rtype = CV_64F;
    Mat cameraMatrix = _cameraMatrix.getMat();
    cameraMatrix = prepareCameraMatrix(cameraMatrix, rtype);
    Mat distCoeffs = _distCoeffs.getMat();
    distCoeffs = prepareDistCoeffs(distCoeffs, rtype);
    if (!(flags & CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL) && (!(flags & CALIB_THIN_PRISM_MODEL)))
        distCoeffs = distCoeffs.rows == 1 ? distCoeffs.colRange(0, 5) : distCoeffs.rowRange(0, 5);

    int    i;
    size_t nimages = _objectPoints.size();
    CV_Assert(nimages > 0);
    Mat objPt, imgPt, npoints, rvecM((int)nimages, 3, CV_64FC1), tvecM((int)nimages, 3, CV_64FC1);
    actually_collectCalibrationData(_objectPoints, _imagePoints, noArray(),
        objPt, imgPt, 0, npoints);
    CvMat c_objPt = objPt, c_imgPt = imgPt, c_npoints = npoints;
    CvMat c_cameraMatrix = cameraMatrix, c_distCoeffs = distCoeffs;
    CvMat c_rvecM = rvecM, c_tvecM = tvecM;

    double reprojErr = cvCalibrateCamera2(&c_objPt, &c_imgPt, &c_npoints, imageSize,
        &c_cameraMatrix, &c_distCoeffs, &c_rvecM,
        &c_tvecM, flags, criteria);

    bool rvecs_needed = _rvecs.needed(), tvecs_needed = _tvecs.needed();

    if (rvecs_needed)
        _rvecs.create((int)nimages, 1, CV_64FC3);
    if (tvecs_needed)
        _tvecs.create((int)nimages, 1, CV_64FC3);

    for (i = 0; i < (int)nimages; i++)
    {
        if (rvecs_needed)
        {
            _rvecs.create(3, 1, CV_64F, i, true);
            Mat rv = _rvecs.getMat(i);
            memcpy(rv.ptr(), rvecM.ptr<double>(i), 3 * sizeof(double));
        }
        if (tvecs_needed)
        {
            _tvecs.create(3, 1, CV_64F, i, true);
            Mat tv = _tvecs.getMat(i);
            memcpy(tv.ptr(), tvecM.ptr<double>(i), 3 * sizeof(double));
        }
    }
    cameraMatrix.copyTo(_cameraMatrix);
    distCoeffs.copyTo(_distCoeffs);

    return reprojErr;
}
static void actually_collectCalibrationData(vector<vector<Point3f>> objectPoints,
    vector<vector<Point2f>> imagePoints1,
    InputArrayOfArrays imagePoints2,
    Mat& objPtMat, Mat& imgPtMat1, Mat* imgPtMat2,
    Mat& npoints)
{
    int nimages = (int)objectPoints.size();
    int i, j = 0, ni = 0, total = 0;
    CV_Assert(nimages > 0 && nimages == (int)imagePoints1.size() &&
        (!imgPtMat2 || nimages == (int)imagePoints2.total()));

    for (i = 0; i < nimages; i++)
    {
        ni = Mat(objectPoints[i]).checkVector(3, CV_32F);
        if (ni <= 0)
            CV_Error(CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "objectPoints should contain vector of vectors of points of type Point3f");
        int ni1 = Mat(imagePoints1[i]).checkVector(2, CV_32F);
        if (ni1 <= 0)
            CV_Error(CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "imagePoints1 should contain vector of vectors of points of type Point2f");
        CV_Assert(ni == ni1);

        total += ni;
    }

    npoints.create(1, (int)nimages, CV_32S);
    objPtMat.create(1, (int)total, CV_32FC3);
    imgPtMat1.create(1, (int)total, CV_32FC2);
    Point2f* imgPtData2 = 0;

    if (imgPtMat2)
    {
        imgPtMat2->create(1, (int)total, CV_32FC2);
        imgPtData2 = imgPtMat2->ptr<Point2f>();
    }

    Point3f* objPtData = objPtMat.ptr<Point3f>();
    Point2f* imgPtData1 = imgPtMat1.ptr<Point2f>();

    for (i = 0; i < nimages; i++, j += ni)
    {
        Mat objpt = Mat(objectPoints[i]);
        Mat imgpt1 = Mat(imagePoints1[i]);
        ni = objpt.checkVector(3, CV_32F);
        npoints.at<int>(i) = ni;
        memcpy(objPtData + j, objpt.ptr(), ni*sizeof(objPtData[0]));
        memcpy(imgPtData1 + j, imgpt1.ptr(), ni*sizeof(imgPtData1[0]));

        if (imgPtData2)
        {
            Mat imgpt2 = imagePoints2.getMat(i);
            int ni2 = imgpt2.checkVector(2, CV_32F);
            CV_Assert(ni == ni2);
            memcpy(imgPtData2 + j, imgpt2.ptr(), ni*sizeof(imgPtData2[0]));
        }
    }
}
static Mat prepareCameraMatrix(Mat& cameraMatrix0, int rtype)
{
    Mat cameraMatrix = Mat::eye(3, 3, rtype);
    if (cameraMatrix0.size() == cameraMatrix.size())
        cameraMatrix0.convertTo(cameraMatrix, rtype);
    return cameraMatrix;
}

static Mat prepareDistCoeffs(Mat& distCoeffs0, int rtype)
{
    Mat distCoeffs = Mat::zeros(distCoeffs0.cols == 1 ? Size(1, 12) : Size(12, 1), rtype);
    if (distCoeffs0.size() == Size(1, 4) ||
        distCoeffs0.size() == Size(1, 5) ||
        distCoeffs0.size() == Size(1, 8) ||
        distCoeffs0.size() == Size(1, 12) ||
        distCoeffs0.size() == Size(4, 1) ||
        distCoeffs0.size() == Size(5, 1) ||
        distCoeffs0.size() == Size(8, 1) ||
        distCoeffs0.size() == Size(12, 1))
    {
        Mat dstCoeffs(distCoeffs, Rect(0, 0, distCoeffs0.cols, distCoeffs0.rows));
        distCoeffs0.convertTo(dstCoeffs, rtype);
    }
    return distCoeffs;
}
```

Errors:

[image]
[image]

Comment: So you want us to comb through your 100's of lines of code an the screenshot of your build error?

Comment: i would suggest you to start commenting out sections and then compiling the code to start removing the errors one by one .If you face problem solving a particular error bring us a simple reprodcible example

Comment: You have lines such as `![file_read]`. That is not legal C++ code. Are those lines in your code on purpose?

Comment: This is code almost entirely copied from OpenCV's camera_calibration calib3d tutorial code, which is why it includes statements like ![file_read].

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you inadvertently changed your code or a build file during the process of trying to track down your original bug. Restore your code to a known-good state using your version control. You do have it under version control, do you not? I would suggest Git if you have the option, or Mercurial.

If you are sure you did not inadvertently change your code or build files, then check to see if your compiler version or tools changed. If your code did not change and your toolchain did not change, then pursue more exotic theories.